# Superscript in an input

Tags: html, input, superscript

Is it possible for a text input tag to take in superscript, and actually display it?

For instance, the Google calculator superscripts with exponents, that would be what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to this [&what](http://www.amp-what.com/unicode/search/super) (or just copy and paste from this post) and click the glyph directly (sometimes you'll need to click the link). Copy and pasting directly is the easiest way.

```css
:root {
  font: 400 16px/1 Consolas
}

input {
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
</head>

<body>
  <input value="X ⁰ ¹ ² ³ ⁴ ⁵ ⁶ ⁷ ⁸ ⁹ ⁺ ⁻ ⁼ ⁽ ⁾ ⁿ °">
</body>

</html>
```